# Datepicker postbacks when lose focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker

When I click textbox datetimepicker popups after that when I click outside of picker to close it, page postbacks but textchange doesn't get fired. either It should not postback page or textchange get fired to fix here. Anyone know how to solve this problem?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=dpStartDateTime.ClientID%>").datepicker({ autoclose: true, weekStart: 1, language: "tr" }).next().on(ace.click_event, function () {
            $(this).prev().focus();
        });
    });
</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="dpStartDateTime" runat="server" CssClass="form-control date-picker" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="dpStartDateTime_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar bigger-110"></i></span>
```

Comment: Please paste your code behind code here. Thank

Answer (score 0):

Change 
`AutoPostback="true"` 
to 
`AutoPostback="false"'

Comment: then OnTextChanged wont get fired?